# Limits of the universe

Tags: cosmology, expansion

I am considering the limit in the expanding universe where the expansion matches the speed of light.

If we consider that the expansion is accelerating, how will the situation be after the next 14 billion years. i.e. after doubling the age of the universe?

Will the distance to this limit not shrink and perhaps come nearer the Hubble limit which I assume have doubled at that time?

I am thinking in newtonian terms so I may have it all wrong.

Comment: This is already happening. There is a distance at which the expansion rate goes faster than light, which creates a cosmic horizon beyond which we cannot reach or receive any further information. Space is expanding, not "stuff", so this doesn't violate relativity.

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii I understand that the expansion may be accellerating. If that is indeed case, I wonder if the radius to the point where the velosity is that of the speed of light also may shrink and come nearer to the Hubble radius.

Comment: Yes, it will, eventually! Read about the "Big Rip"